# Radio Mobile on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, wine

Does anyone have experience setting up Radio Mobile, on Wine, in Ubuntu? There is such little data online, I am really hoping some could help me with the installation on Wine.

I tried to use the Radio Mobile installer but I get the following error:

```
root@x-K56CB:/home/x# wine Downloads/Radio_Mobile_Setup.exe
err:module:import_dll Library MSVBVM60.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Radio Mobile\\rmweng.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\Radio Mobile\\rmweng.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

The solution is to install VB6run, which I did using winetricks, but I still keep getting the same error... is it perhaps because I am installing it in a directory outside of  .wine?

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What were the exact errors that you received? Please edit your question to provide any and all pertinent details. Thanks.